# PlayFramework beginner. Route definition error

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a made a simple new controller and tried to define my routes. Everything seems to be correct but I get an error. The code is taken from the Manning Play for Java.

Products Controller:

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.*;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class Products extends Controller {

//list all products
public static Result list(){
    return TODO;
}

//return empty form for adding
public static Result newProduct(){
    return TODO;
}

//product edit form
public static Result details(String ean){
    return TODO;
}

//save a product
public static Result save(){
    return TODO;
}

}
```

Routes:

```
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index

GET     /count                      controllers.CountController.count

GET     /message                    controllers.AsyncController.message


GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)

GET     /products                   controllers.Products.list
GET     /products/new               controllers.Products.newProduct
GET     /products/:ean              controllers.Products.details(ean: String)
POST    /products/                  controllers.Products.save
```

Errors:

```
Compiling 6 Scala sources and 11 Java sources to /Users/andrei/Desktop/PlayFramework/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /Users/andrei/Desktop/PlayFramework/conf/routes:15: value list is not a member of controllers.Products
[error] GET     /products                   controllers.Products.list
[error] /Users/andrei/Desktop/PlayFramework/conf/routes:16: value newProduct is not a member of controllers.Products
[error] GET     /products/new               controllers.Products.newProduct
[error] /Users/andrei/Desktop/PlayFramework/conf/routes:17: value details is not a member of controllers.Products
[error] GET     /products/:ean              controllers.Products.details(ean: String)
[error] /Users/andrei/Desktop/PlayFramework/conf/routes:18: value save is not a member of controllers.Products
[error] POST    /products/                  controllers.Products.save
[error] four errors found
```

Comment: try using 'return ok()' instead of 'return TODO'

Comment: @AsadSarwar, TODO is not a problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 2.5, Play starts using `InjectedRoutesGenerator`, which will prohibit `static` controllers methods. So, simple solution will be to remove `static` keyword.

But, if you really want to have static methods (I don't see why), you could user legacy (pre 2.5.0) `static` routes generator, that assumes that all actions are `static` 
methods

> You can configure Play to use the legacy (pre 2.5.0) static routes
>   generator, that assumes that all actions are static methods. To
>   configure the project, add the following to build.sbt:
>
> routesGenerator := StaticRoutesGenerator We recommend always using the
>   injected routes generator. The static routes generator exists
>   primarily as a tool to aid migration so that existing projects don’t
>   have to make all their controllers non static at once.
>
> If using the static routes generator, you can indicate that an action
>   has an injected controller by prefixing the action with @, like so:
>
> GET        /some/path        @controllers.Application.index()